# OpenCV - Too many false positives in license place detection

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm using OpenCV with Haar Cascade (Python) to detect license plates in photos. I'm trying the allready trained eu.xml file from [openalpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/runtime_data/region). The plates are mostly swedish.

I'm getting a bit too many false positives while still missing some:[image][image]

Many of the false positives are in the asphalt or on the road signs. Here are the parameters for detection:

```
lp_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('assets/cascades/eu.xml')
img = cv.imread(filepath)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plates = lp_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 2, cv.CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (20, 8), (150, 50))
```

My question is if anyone have an idea of how to reduce the amount of false positives while still maintaining or even improving the hitrate? Either by adjusting the parameters or filtering out bad matches in pre-/post-processing? I've tried a lot to play around with the parameters but these are giving the best result so far. A high hitrate is required.

**Update:**

Grayscale images:
[image]
[image]

Also examples with license plates:
This one is currently missed:
[image]

But this one is found:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a grayscale image of what you're passing to the classifier?

Comment: Blurring/smoothing input image before processing might help.

Comment: I added a few grayscale samples, both with and without plates. 

I'll give that a try Mika.

Comment: can you try to find the cascade code used in OpenALPR? Are you sure that the classifiers are to detect plates? Does it work on some images?

Comment: The code that calls the cascade method is in https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/b9293e00d968c37606d01dda9fdfbdf1863cd7f1/src/openalpr/detection/detectorcpu.cpp default detection_iteration_increase is 1.1 and default detectionStrictness is 3. I lowered the strictness to 2 since it missed too many.

Comment: can you try to omit the canny pruning?

Comment: Blurring the photo did reduce false positives. Unfortunately it also reduced the hitrate. I tried gaussian blur of different sizes (grayBlurred = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)). Disabling pruning didn't make any difference.